# integral one variable out in multiple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a function $\;f$: $\mathcal{R}^d\rightarrow\mathcal{R}$, and **x,y,z** $\in \mathcal{R}^d$ are spatial coordinate vector.

Could we express:
$\int\; f($**x-z**$)f($**y+z**$) \;d$**z** as a functional of $f($**x+y**$)$, for example $(f($**x+y**$))^2$

Comment: Your notation for $f^2$ is ambiguous. Do you mean $f\left(f\left(\bf x+\bf y\right)\right)$ or do you mean $(f(\bf x + \bf y))^2$?

Comment: Also, does f also produce a vector in $R^d$ ?

Comment: Hi, $f$ is a scalar function and f^2 indicate (f(x))^2.